# Two-way communications (ask or tell)?

Tags: java, akka, akka-camel

**akka documentation for java says**

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/camel.html#Consumer_timeout

Two-way communications between a Camel endpoint and an actor are initiated by sending the request message to the actor with the **ask** pattern and the actor replies to the endpoint when the response is ready.

**And then**

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/java/camel.html#Asynchronous_routing

A consumer endpoint sends request messages to its consumer actor using the **tell** method and the actor returns responses with getSender().**tell** once they are ready.

**Which of both statements is true?** 
**Does it depend on the Camel component?**

**If tell method is used, how does the endpoint know to which client respond?**

Thanks.